# Create a generic repository DropDown with SelectListItem in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, repository, mvc-editor-templates

Having returned to this problem after a few months I've added my current best answer below.

In the original question I was still looking for a simple way to achieve a generic DropDown but the title was more closely tied to the specific error I was then facing.

I've amended the title to reflect the answer more closely. Hopefully this might help someone.

---

Original Question:

### Generic Editor Template for DropDownListFor throws Cannot convert type error

I'm trying to create a generic template for a drop down list using ideas lifted from the follwing post:

[Move Html DropDownListFor into Editor Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219335/move-html-dropdownlistfor-into-editortemplate)

I've created a DropDownHelper class:

```
public class DDLOptions<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I've amended the Controller from this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new FilmEditViewModel();

        FilmDropDownViewModel films = new FilmDropDownViewModel
            {
                Items = _repo.GetSelect(),                    
            };

        model.filmName = films;           
        return View(model);
    }
```

...to this:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new FilmEditViewModel();

        DDLOptions<FilmDropDownViewModel> films
            = new DDLOptions<FilmDropDownViewModel>
            {
                Items = _repo.GetSelect()
            };

        model.filmName = films;           
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is throwing the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
'BootstrapSupport.DDLOptions<FilmStore.ViewModels.FilmDropDownViewModel>' 
to 'FilmStore.ViewModels.FilmDropDownViewModel'
```

I'm also having difficulty working out how to amend the Editor Template to work with the modified `DDLOptions` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to create a generic DropDown which I've mangled together from a few pointers on StackOverflow and this article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/682454/MVC-Generic-Dropdownlist-for-Razor). Comments on whether this follows best practice would be appreciated.

I use both an AddList and an EditList to allow for a selected item on the EditList and some jQuery based on html class attributes. The generic EditList is created as follows:

## Models

I have a viewmodel for any DropDown that fits with the generic pattern and then a ViewModel for the entity I'm returning. Annotations are held in a validation file.

### DropDown ViewModel

```
public class DropDownViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

### Entity ViewModel

```
public partial class OrganisationEditViewModel
{
    public int entityID { get; set; }
    public string entityName { get; set; }
    public DropDownViewModel entityTypeID { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
}
```

### Validation

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(OrganisationEditViewModelMetaData))]
public partial class OrganisationEditViewModel
{

}

public class OrganisationEditViewModelMetaData
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int entityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Organisation")]
    public string entityName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Entity Type")]
    [UIHint("_dropDownEdit")]
    public DropDownViewModel entityTypeID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Notes")]
    public string notes { get; set; }

}
```

## Editor Template

The UIHint annotation on the ViewModel points to an Editor Template. I'm using [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) on my lookups, hence the html attributes.

```
@model WhatWorks.ViewModels.DropDownViewModel

@Html.DropDownList("", Model.Items, new { @class = "chosen chosenLookup" })
```

## Controller

The controller queries the current entity to get the selected string for the EditList. The DropDown is called from the `GetEditList<O>` function in the repository. The ViewModel is then mapped via [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) (`GetUpdate(id)`).

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    var query = _repo.GetByID(id);
    string selected = query.tEntityType.entityTypeID.ToString();

    DropDownViewModel entityType = new DropDownViewModel
    {
        Items = _repo.GetEditList<tEntityType>("entityType", "entityTypeID", selected)
    };

    OrganisationEditViewModel a = GetUpdate(id);
    a.entityTypeID = entityType;

    if (a == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(a);
}
```

## Repository

The generic DropDown repository method gets an `IEnumerable` set of data from the calling type `<O>` (`tEntityType` in this case). The `return` method converts everything into strings and checks for the selected item.

```
//generic Edit dropdown
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetEditList<O>(string text, string value, string selected) 
                                                        where O : class
    {
        IEnumerable<O> result = context.Set<O>();
        var query = from e in result
                    select new
                    {
                        Value = e.GetType().GetProperty(value).GetValue(e, null),
                        Text = e.GetType().GetProperty(text).GetValue(e, null)
                    };

        return query.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.Value.ToString(),
                Text = s.Text.ToString(),
                Selected = (selected == s.Value.ToString() ? true : false)
            });
    }
```

## View

Finally, the view renders the DropDown via a standard `Html.Editor` which picks up the Editor Template from the `UIHint` annotation on the validation file.