# Selecting from table name passed as argument in MVC Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, arguments, repository-pattern, multiple-tables

I am working on a MVC4 project which makes use of Unit of Work and Repository patterns. I have around 25 tables which are only read only tables for Dropdown or Multiselect list. The list might increase in future as we add new modules. I was wondering if I can implement a generic repository which returns a select or multiselect list depending upon table name (or some alias) I pass a an argument to the function.

For eg.

> public class GenericListReopsitory<'T> where T is Entity
>   {
>
> public SelectList GetDropDownList()
>     {
>
> }
>
> public MultiSelectList GetMultiSelectList()
>      {
>
> }
>
> }

and then to access in Controller,

> ViewBag.RoleDropDownList = Uow.GenericListObj<'Role_Master>.GetDropDownList()

Is it possible to implement something like this in repository pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do both `DropDown` and `MultiSelect` Lists through a generic repository.

I've already [answered my own question about `DropDowns`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005977) so I won't repeat that.

A `MultiSelect` list uses the same technique for a blank list but you need something else if you want to edit the list whilst showing the current selections (as with the above link, I use [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to render the `MultiSelect` input box).

### Models

There is a ViewModel for the `MultiSelectList` which I call from the main ViewModel. The validation is held in a separate file.

### MultiSelect ViewModel

```
public class MultiSelectViewModel
{
    public MultiSelectList Items { get; set; }
}
```

### Entity ViewModel

```
public partial class InterventionTypeEditViewModel
{
    public int interventionTypeID { get; set; }
    public string interventionType { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectViewModel outcomeID { get; set; }
}
```

### Validation

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(InterventionTypeEditViewModelMetaData))]
public partial class InterventionTypeEditViewModel
{

}

public class InterventionTypeEditViewModelMetaData
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int interventionTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Intervention Type")]
    public string interventionType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Outcome")]
    [UIHint("_multiEdit")]
    public string outcomeID { get; set; }

}
```

### Editor Template

The `[UIHint("_multiEdit")]` points to the following editor template. The class attributes are for [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) and the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework.

```
@model WhatWorks.ViewModels.MultiSelectViewModel

@Html.DropDownList("", Model.Items, null, new { @class = "chosen input-xxlarge", multiple = "multiple", })
```

### Controller

In the controller I call the repository twice - once for the controllers owner entity (in this case `tInterventionType`) and once for the entity that will supply our `MultiSelectList` values (`tOutcome`). The `_repo` instance refers to the generic type parameter T in the standard generic CRUD, Get and GetById methods. The _multi instance uses a generic type parameter O to differentiate the entity in the repository. This may not be best practice (advice welcome) but it works.

```
    private readonly IAdminRepository<tInterventionType> _repo;
    private readonly IAdminRepository<tOutcome> _multi;

    public InterventionTypeController(IAdminRepository<tInterventionType> _repo,
                                        IAdminRepository<tOutcome> _multi)
    {
        this._repo = _repo;
        this._multi = _multi;
    }
```

Then in the `GET` request for the `Edit` action, `selectFrom` returns all the items for the select list whist `currentSelect` returns the items that are already selected.
The `MultiSelectViewModel` is then populated using [this `MultiSelectList` constructor.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470158(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
    // GET: /InterventionType/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {            
        var selectFrom = _multi.Get();
        IEnumerable<int> currentSelect = from o in selectFrom
                            where o.tInterventionType.Any(m => m.interventionTypeID == id)
                            select o.outcomeID;

        MultiSelectViewModel outcome = new MultiSelectViewModel
        {
            Items = new MultiSelectList(selectFrom, "outcomeID", "outcome", currentSelect)
        };

        InterventionTypeEditViewModel a = GetUpdate(id);
        a.outcomeID = outcome;
        if (a == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(a);
    }
```

### Repository

The method in the repository is the same as a standard `Get()` but the generic type parameter O refers to the model that is passed

```
    public IEnumerable<O> GetMultiSelectEntity<O>()
                            where O : class
    {
        return context.Set<O>().ToList();
    }
```

### View

As with the standard `DropDown`, the view renders the `MultiSelectList` via an Html.Editor which picks up the Editor Template from the UIHint annotation on the validation file.

---

## Adding/Editing

To add/edit the MultiSelect I use a separate generic `Find` in the repository to return the child collection object. The selected items are then added in the controller.

### Repository

Return an entity for the child collection using a different generic class (O).

```
    public O GetMulti<O>(int id) 
                    where O : class
    {
        return context.Set<O>().Find(id);
    }
```

### Controller

To create a new instance of the parent object, `Insert` the parent and then iterate over the collection of child objects, adding each in turn.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(InterventionTypeAddViewModel model) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var a = new tInterventionType();
            a.InjectFrom(model);
            _repo.Insert(a);

            foreach (var outcomeId in model.outcome)
            {
                tOutcome o = _repo.GetMulti<tOutcome>(outcomeId);
                a.tOutcome.Add(o as tOutcome);                    
            }

            _repo.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

To edit an existing parent object, [clear the child collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116791/50179) and add the currently selected items as per the create method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(InterventionTypeUpdateViewModel model, int id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var a = _repo.GetById(id);
            a.InjectFrom(model);
            a.interventionTypeID = id;
            _repo.Update(a);

            //clear the child collection (outcome on interventionType)
            a.tOutcome.Clear();

            //Add current selection
            foreach (var outcomeId in model.outcomeID)
            {
                tOutcome o = _repo.GetMulti<tOutcome>(outcomeId);
                a.tOutcome.Add(o as tOutcome); 
            }

            _repo.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```