# Entity Framework Generic Repository SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-design

I am implementing the generic repository pattern in my MVC project and am following this tutorial.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I love this idea of using one repository for all entities.
I am struggling with implementing a generic method to return a SelectListItem for my ListBoxFor.

Here is my method in the repository.

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListName(Expression<Func<TEntity, SelectListItem>> select)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
        return query.Select(select);
        //return dbSet.ToList().Select(s => new SelectListItem
        //{
        //    Text = s.LName + ", " + s.FName,
        //    Value = s.PersonID.ToString()
        //});
    }
```

As you can see I want to concatenate the persons first and last name. I am struggling at this point because I am not sure if this is the best way to do this.

```
 People = unitOfWork.Repository.GetSelectListName(e => e.LName);//not sure here??
```

Comment: I've posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23480813/50179) regarding generic dropdown lists. You could add a `fullname` string to your ViewModel and map the concatenation outside of the `GetSelectListName` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do somethink like that

```
People = unitOfWork.Repository.GetSelectListName (e => new SelectListItem({Text= string.Format("{0} {1})", e.LName, e.FName), Value=e.PersonID});
```

Comment: I think the syntax in your answer was wrong so I changed it to GetSelectListName(e => string.Format("{0} {1}", e.LName, e.FName))  Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'

Comment: it looks like you are returning a new SelectListItem and not a string either change you IEnumerable<SelectListItem>  to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> or do like in the edit